# Is a desire for vindication a legitimate reason for a lawsuit?

Tags: international, british-columbia, legal-concepts, ohio

I understate that a judge can often determine a monetary payment for the violation of a law.

But, what if the primary motive for undertaking a law suit is to not be the fool of the other?

Is it better to pretend the dispute is just about money, when it is really all about one's honor?

Answer (score 4):

### It can be

Defamation suits, in particular, are often undertaken to vindicate reputation rather than to secure monetary damages. This is one reason why suits awarding nominal damages for libel (sums such as $1, or six-pence or  one farthing in the UK) are sometimes regarded as victories by plaintiffs, even though such plaintiffs gained no money, and in some cases had to spend much time,. effort, and money to get such a verdict. In other cases such low damages are known as "contemptuous damages" expressing the view that "Yes you were technically defamed, but your reputation was of no value". The damages of one half-penny awarded in [*Dering v Uris and Others* (1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dering_v_Uris) had been taken in this latter sense.

See also the Wikippedia section on ["Nominal damages"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damages#Nominal_damages) where it is stated that:

> The [US] Supreme Court decided 8–1 in the 2021 case [*Uzuegbunam v. Preczewski*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzuegbunam_v._Preczewski) that nominal damages are appropriate means to redress violated rights otherwise now rendered moot.

In some kinds of cases in some jurisdictions a plaintiff may indicate that s/he does not desire monetary damages, only a judgement supporting his or her position. In other cases a suit must be framed as one for monetary damages, but the plaintiff may state that the verdict, not the damages, is what is most desired.

There is noting illegal nor (in my view) immoral in bringing a suit more for public vindication than for money damages. There is, of course, a risk that the case will not turn out as the plaintiff wishes. Whether a states lack of interest in damages will favorably or unfavorably impress the judge or jury can vary widely, and cannot be predicted in general.

Defamation case verdicts sometimes include an order for one side to apologize to the other. Whether such an apology has value is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

### Courts can’t order the restitution of “honor”

In essence, there are only three things a court can do:

- make an order for payment of money
- make an order for someone to do some act
- make an order prohibiting someone from doing act.

A plaintiff who can’t state which of these they want and the legal basis for why they are entitled to it will have their case dismissed.

Comment: A plaintiff can ask for "such relief as the court considers just". showing legal grounds for why s/he was injured. An " order for someone to do some act" can include an order to make a public apology.

Comment: @DavidSiegel sure. But the court can’t order “restoration of honour”

Comment: No, the court cannot **order** that. But the plaintiff may legitimatly hope that a favorable verdict will leads to the "restoration of honor" in the eys of the public, or a significant part of the public. And the plaintiff need not specify just what remedy is desired (although plaintiffs usually do) as your answer states. The plaintiff may choose to leave that to the court. [...]

Comment: [...] The plaintiff must, in most jurisdictions, state what event entitle the plaintiff to relief of some sort. The details of what the plaintiff must state, and in how much detail, vary significantly by jurisdiction, and have varied over time (in ,uch of the US, Common-law pleading -> Field code -> FRCP during the 20th Century) Not all US states have, I understand, adopted FRCP. (but maybe that is out of date)

Comment: A fourth thing, which also doesn't necessarily restore honor is to declare the rights of the parties in the case of a contract, statute, or ownership dispute in which there is a bona fide and immediate genuine dispute of law that will impact how the parties act, such as a "quiet title action" or a "declaratory judgment" action.

Comment: @DavidSiegel This is still true and includes very importantly both California and New York State whose civil procedure rules are not modeled upon the federal rules.

Comment: @DavidSiegel In a civil action, generally speaking, in the U.S., a court can't order a party to make a public apology.